# Does Hyperopt support subset of choices?

Tags: python, hyperopt

I have a set of choices *A*. I would like to get back a subset of choices *A*. Is this possible with Hyperopt?

*input:*

```
{
    'A': hp.choice('A', [0, 1, 2, 3])
}
```

*output:*

```
{
    'A': [0, 2]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but if you specifically want that functionality, there are multiple ways to do so.

1. You can define a new expression and add it to existing hyperopt parameter expressions as given in [the documentation](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#23-adding-non-stochastic-expressions-with-pyll). For example, in your case, you can do:

   ```
   import hyperopt.pyll
   from hyperopt.pyll import scope
   from hyperopt.pyll.stochastic import sample

   # Add a new method as you want
   @scope.define
   def foo(choices, num_choices):
       return np.random.choice(choices, size=num_choices, replace=False)

   choices = [1,2,3,4]

   # Define the space like below and use in fmin
   space = scope.foo(choices, 2)

   # Call this multiple times to see how space behaves
   print(sample(space))
   ```

   See the [documention of numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to know how that works.

   **Note**:

   - The `foo` method will return a subset of choices (in a numpy array). So make sure that in your objective function, you are using the internal multiple values like `x[0], x[1], ...` etc.
   - Add `scope.undefine(foo)` in the end of your code, or else you will have to restart your terminal / kernel each time before running the code.
   - The hyperopt wiki [specifically prohibits](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#24-adding-new-kinds-of-hyperparameter) to define new types of parameter search spaces just as we did above because that may affect the search strategy or perform non-optimally.
2. If **you are allowed to choose two values with replacement** (that means that sometimes both values in the subset will be same. This is the reason we used `replace=False` in point 1), then the following can be done:

   ```
   choices = [1,2,3,4]
   space = [hp.choice('c1', choices), 
            hp.choice('c2', choices)]
   ```

   Then in your objective function, you can access your two values as `x[0]`, `x[1]`.

   But from your question, it seems like you want to have the sub-choices and that implies without replacement, so a sub-set of `[1,1]` or `[2,2]` etc. is invalid. In that case, you should use the [`Trials` object to define `status`](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#12-attaching-extra-information-via-the-trials-object).

A sample program for point 2 is below:

```
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, STATUS_OK, STATUS_FAIL, Trials

def objective(x):
    # Check if the supplied choices are valid or not
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    if x1 == x2:
        # If invalid, only return the status and hyperopt will understand
        return {'status': STATUS_FAIL} 


    # Normal flow of objective
    # Do your coding here

    # In the end, return this  
    return {
        'loss': actual_loss,  # Fill the actual loss here
        'status': STATUS_OK
        }

choices = [1,2,3,4]
space = [hp.choice('c1', choices), 
         hp.choice('c2', choices)]

trials = Trials()   
best = fmin(objective, space=space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100, trials=trials)

from hyperopt import space_eval
print(space_eval(space, best))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, though the code is a little more cumbersome. Define each element of A seperately as a choice between inclusion and exclusion. For example:

```
space = {
    "A0": hp.choice("A0", [False, True]),
    "A1": hp.choice("A1", [False, True]),
    "A2": hp.choice("A2", [False, True]),
    ...
}
```

Code to interpret this in your objective function is pretty easy as well:

```
A = [i for i in range(num_choices) if space["A"+str(i)]]
# A = [0, 2] for example
```

This will return true random subsets of the A (anywhere from an empty set to the entirety of A).